# What's the ufunc to do floor division in numpy with python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, division, numpy-ufunc

In python 2.x, I can use the universal function `numpy.divide` to do floor division. However, the ufunc `divide` and `true_divide` both do true division in python 3.x.

```
In [24]: np.divide([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
Out[24]: array([ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ])

In [25]: np.true_divide([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
Out[25]: array([ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ])
```

So what is the universal function in numpy with python3 to do floor division?

Comment: It's kind of silly to call the explicit functions, when you can just use `/` and `//` (for true and floor division respectively). `//` always works the same way in Python 2, and `/` can be made to work as true division in Py2 by including `from __future__ import division` at the top of your module.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sometimes I prefer ufunc. Since the ufunc can accept array like objects i.e. list, tuple, iterator etc.  as the example I given in the question, which operator like // can't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the NumPy ufunc [`np.floor_divide`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.floor_divide.html):

```
>>> np.floor_divide([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
array([0, 1, 1, 2])
```

Alternatively you can use the `//` operator:

```
>>> a = np.array([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
>>> a // 2
array([-1, -1,  0,  0,  1])
```